# What can cause the Oct 2011 OTA update of the Galaxy Tab 10.1 to fail?

Tags: samsung-kies, 3.1-honeycomb, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, ota-update

I'm using a Galaxy Tab 10.1 3G (GT-P7500), Android 3.1, Baseband version P7500XXKG7, Build HMJ37 P7500XWKG9, rooted. (I got it *with* 3.1 and TouchWiz preinstalled.)

A few weeks ago, I got a notification about an OTA update. The only information I get about this update is:

```
Update details (9.61MB)
Improved stability.
```

Trying to install this update reproducibly fails. It downloads, then asks me whether to install. I confirm, and it tells me that it will reboot the device. The device reboots. During the reboot animation, I see a low-resolution progress bar that runs until about 25%. Then it reboots again, I enter my PIN and it tells me: "Failed to update firmware. Try again using PC software (Kies) or visit a Samsung service centre". It does not give me any details as to why it has failed.

I connected DDMS to the device during the update, but (as expected) it doesn't show anything during that phase. I don't know how to get any additional reporting as to why the update failed.

I can't connect the device to Kies either. Again, it doesn't report the problem. Kies notices when I connect the device, then says: "Reconnect the device in Samsung Kies (PC Studio) mode.Current connection mode not supported by Kies." (sic!)

What can cause an OTA update to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating via Kies eventually worked. The trick to getting Kies to connect to the device is to turn off USB debugging on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I read that missing system apps can cause this problem. I unfroze the following stock apps:

- Ap Mobile
- eBook
- Music Hub
- My Files
- Pulse
- Social Hub

Comment: This had no effect on the update. Still fails exactly the same way.